# Execute code on confirmation of shipment

Tags: acumatica

I want to execute some code (to change the shipment date) upon the 'Confirm Shipment' action on the Shipments screen (SO302000).

I was thinking that this would be the way to do it:

```
public class SOShipmentEntryExt : PXGraphExtension<SOShipmentEntry>
{
    [PXOverride]
    public virtual void ConfirmShipment(SOOrderEntry docgraph, SOShipment shiporder)
    {
        Base.ConfirmShipment(docgraph, shiporder);
        //Add my code to do something here...
    }

}
```

When I try this, I get a shipment counter error.  Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You can find a really similar case here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39211401/how-to-add-custom-business-logic-to-acumatica-frameworks-actions/39211402#39211402

Comment: Ah - beautiful, thanks..   So, I guess that doesn't really 'replace' the original Actions button, since all the other options are still there, even though the Action code in the graph extension only has one option - Confirm Shipment - in it...  Not sure HOW it works - but it works.

Comment: Well you could override the ConfirmShipment method, but you would also have to copy paste all the original code as to not break the function. If what you really need is a bit of pre processing before calling the original method, I think the solution from the link I gave is easier and cleaner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a similar case: 
[How to add custom business logic to Acumatica framework's Actions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39211401/how-to-add-custom-business-logic-to-acumatica-frameworks-actions)

```
public class SOShipmentEntryExt : PXGraphExtension<SOShipmentEntry>
{

    public PXAction<SOShipment> action;
    [PXButton]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Actions", MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Select)]
    protected IEnumerable Action(PXAdapter adapter
                                ,[PXIntList(new int[] { 1 }
                                ,new string[] { "Confirm Shipment" })
                                ,PXInt] int? actionID)
    {
        //actionID = 1 means the Confirm Shipment action was the one invoked
        if (actionID == 1)
        {

            Base.Document.Current.ShipDate = Base.Accessinfo.BusinessDate;
            Base.Document.Update(Base.Document.Current);
        }

        //calls the basic action that was invoked
        return Base.action.Press(adapter);
    }

}
```